# help with setup of .htaccess file redirects

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I need help configuring my .htaccess file to handle redirects properly.

Here’s what I need to have happen. Stackoverflow's spam filter wouldn't allow me to post the full domain.  So where I say "DOMAIN" you can substitue "domain.com". (I also needed to add and extra t to the http.)

1. Requests for the `DOMAIN/page` version of the file should be redirected to `www.DOMAIN/page`.
2. Requests for the 'friendly' versions of the URLS should be allowed. So a file that is really at `www.DOMAIN/index.php?q=37` should be viewable by going to `www.DOMAIN/latest-news`
3. I have a big list of 301 redirects. We recently changed the site from an .asp based CMS to one written in PHP.

Example:

```
redirect 301 /overview.asp http://www.DOMAIN/overview
```

Items 1 and 2 are working fine.

However for item 3, if I put in a browser request for "http://www.DOMAIN/overview.asp" instead of redirecting to the friendly name of the file ("http://www.DOMAIN/overview") it will redirect to `http://www.DOMAIN/index.php?q=overview.asp`.  This is the problem.

What do I need to change to get this working right?

My configuration is below:

```
## Fix Apache internal dummy connections from breaking [(site_url)] cache
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

## Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets)/*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

## For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.DOMAIN/$1 [R=301,L]

redirect 301 /overview.asp http://www.DOMAIN/overview
redirect 301 /news.asp http://www.DOMAIN/news
#  ETC....
```

thanks!

Comment: please edit and use code blocks to make your code readable.

Comment: So what _should_ it do when you go to `/overview.asp`?

Comment: What is your question? "a and b are working fine" - I take it you mean 1&2? "if I put in this request instead of redirecting to the friendly name of the file it will redirect to ..." - put what request in. Should it, what do you want this to do? It is late here but I have read your post several times and have no clue. Are you saying that any asp page requested should get passed as parameter q to index.php?

Comment: I edited to try and clarify the question. Sorry for the ambiguity. If you try to go to /overview.asp it should go to the 'friendly' version of the page '/overview' listed in the 301 redirect instead of 'http://www.DOMAIN/index.php?q=overview.asp'

Comment: I'd expect your current code to go to `http://www.example.com/overview?q=overview.asp`, actually (which is also not what you wanted). But it displays `http://www.example.com/index.php?q=overview.asp` in the browser's URL bar?

Answer (score 0):

Mod_rewrite is doing exactly what you're asking it to do ... (yes :-), that's often the problem with computers).

On the `/overview.asp http://www.DOMAIN/overview` line you're setting the browser to send out a brand new request from scratch, which starts the whole cycle again from the top and gets catched by the `^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1` directive.

Right before this line you should put another RewriteCond to prevent the `^(.*)$` rule to apply if REQUEST_FILENAME is either *overview* or *news*. You might also simply rewrite */overview.asp* to *overview* [L] instead of redirecting.

If you can, set the RewriteLog directive to its highest verbosity and look at the logfile - it usually gives very good insights into what's really going on...

EDIT - if I get it right you shoud be doing this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! \.asp$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! ^overview$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! ^news$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This would prevent any file already ending in .asp, plus those looking for overview and news,  to be redirected toward index.php.

I suspect anyway that you got something backwards regarding that SEO stuff. You should indeed start from the structure of the query string that your scripts expect and use that as a base to build a sensible URL addressing schema.

EDIT #2:

There was a space too many between the bang mark ant the regex. The following code doesn't come from memory as the previous -  I've tested on my local Apache and it does what's supposed to do (as long as I've understood correctly..)

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.asp$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !overview$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !news$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: And, BTW, wht are you doing this? The common SEO practice in URL rewriting is to have the world at large send in requests for the friendly URL and then rewrite it into a real filename, not the other way round.

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing this because SEO best practices says you always want to do a 301 redirect to the friendly URL. If you do this then this is the URL that will get cached by Google.  You never want to tell Google to cache a page that looks like 'index.asp?q=50&h=10'. I don't know much about .htaccess files but I'm pretty confident of this.

Comment: How can I do the the RewriteCond to NOT apply if the request coming in is for a '.asp' file?  I have about 15 301 redirects and they are all .asp's.

Comment: Hi, I tried this and got a 500 error. I think we're going down the right path though...